# rotation matrix to axis angle

Tags: matrices, 3d, coordinate-systems, rotations

from wikipedia the above rotation matrix has a rotation of -74 degrees. What does it mean "around the axis (−1⁄3,2⁄3,2⁄3)"? How can I determine how many degrees is rotated on X axis, Y axis and Z axis?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axis of a rotation in $\Bbb R^3$ is the line which remains unchanged by the rotation.  Think of twirling an umbrella around its shaft - the shaft always stays in the same place and this is the axis of the rotation.

The angle is measured in a plane perpendicular to the axis.  So, pick any vector perpendicular to the axis; find the vector which results from rotating this vector; the angle of the rotation means the angle between these vectors.

It does not really make any sense to ask for the angle of rotation "on the $x$ axis".

The easiest way to find the angle is to use the formula
$$1+2\cos\theta={\rm trace}(Q)\ ,$$
where ${\rm trace}(Q)$ means the sum of the diagonal elements of $Q$.  In this case
$${\rm trace}(Q)=0.36+0.60+0.60\ .$$

You can find the axis from the fact that it is an eigenvector of $Q$ corresponding to eigenvalue $1$.  That is, solve $(Q-I){\bf v}=\bf0$ to find the axis $\bf v$.

Comment: I am new in this field and I don't understand the whole answer very well.. But let me ask you. Let's assume the umbrella or any other vector in a 3-dimensional space. Someone says rotate the umbrella or the vector at -74 degrees around the axis (−1⁄3,2⁄3,2⁄3). Is it possible to do that? My question might sounds stupid but as I said I have no much experience..

Comment: You would just point the umbrella shaft in the indicated direction and turn it so that the shaft stays in the same place and the spokes of the umbrella move through the required angle.

Comment: David hello again! This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022630/how-to-calculate-the-angle-from-roational-matrix what I was looking for! Maybe my question was not well defined...

Comment: Had a look at that link but it doesn't make any sense to me.  Sorry.  The Euler angles are not the angle of rotation but I don't know what they are.